# How to find the version of teradataml package?

Tags: python, teradata

How to find out the version of teradataml package?
It doesn't expose .**version** attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**
On the terminal run - 
`pip freeze | grep teradataml`

**Method 2**
Using API -

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("teradataml").version
```

Answer (score 0):

In terminal type `pip freeze` or `pip3 freeze`. It will show all the packages with their versions.

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/teradataml/

Try running pip install command

> pip install teradataml